# How to perform SumIf using VBA on an array in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to come up with the fastest way to perform a SumIf function in Excel on a dataset that has approx. 110'000 lines. I've come up with three ways, but none of them are satisfying.

Here the first one I tried: Execution time on my PC 100 seconds!

```
    Sub Test1_WorksheetFunction()

Dim MaxRow As Long, MaxCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim StartTimer, EndTimer, UsedTime

StartTimer = Now()

With wsTest
    MaxRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    MaxCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 2 To MaxRow
        .Cells(i, 4) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(wsData.Range("G2:G108840"), .Cells(i, 1), wsData.Range("R2:R108840"))
    Next i

End With

EndTimer = Now()
MsgBox (DateDiff("s", StartTimer, EndTimer))

End Sub
```

Here is the second Method: Execution Time a bit better at 55 seconds

```
Sub Test2_Formula_and_Copy()

Dim MaxRow As Long, MaxCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim StartTimer, EndTimer, UsedTime

StartTimer = Now()

With wsTest
    MaxRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    MaxCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count

    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIF(Tabelle1[KUNDENBESTELLNR],Test!RC[-3],Tabelle1[ANZAHL NACHFRAGE])"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D6285")
    Range("D2:D6285").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End With

EndTimer = Now()
MsgBox (DateDiff("s", StartTimer, EndTimer))

End Sub
```

Third attempt: Execution so slow it never finished.

```
Sub Test3_Read_in_Array()

Dim MaxRow As Long, MaxCol As Long
Dim SearchRange() As String, SumRange() As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k
Dim StartTimer, EndTimer, UsedTime
Dim TempValue

StartTimer = Now()

With wsData
    MaxRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ReDim SearchRange(1 To MaxRow)
    ReDim SumRange(1 To MaxRow)
    For i = 1 To MaxRow
        SearchRange(i) = .Range("G" & (1 + i)).Value
        SumRange(i) = .Range("R" & (1 + i)).Value
    Next i
End With

With wsTest
    MaxRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To MaxRow
        For j = LBound(SearchRange) To UBound(SearchRange)
            k = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            If k = SearchRange(j) Then
            TempValue = TempValue + SumRange(j)
            End If
        Next j
        .Cells(i, 4) = TempValue
    Next i
End With


EndTimer = Now()
MsgBox (DateDiff("s", StartTimer, EndTimer))

End Sub
```

Clearly I have not yet mastered VBA (or any other programming language for that matter). Can someone help me in getting this to be efficient? There must be a way! Right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’d been searching for a faster method for calculating Sumifs for some time when I came up with the following solution.  Instead of using Sumifs, you concatenate the values used in the criteria ranges as a single value, then using simple If formulas – combined with one range Sort – you achieve the same results as if you’d used Sumifs.

In my own case, using Sumifs with 25K rows and 2 criteria ranges to evaluate was taking 18.4 seconds on average – using the If and Sort method, it was taking 0.67 seconds on average.

```
 Sub FasterThanSumifs()
    'FasterThanSumifs Concatenates the criteria values from columns A and B -
    'then uses simple IF formulas (plus 1 sort) to get the same result as a sumifs formula

    'Columns A & B contain the criteria ranges, column C is the range to sum
    'NOTE: The data is already sorted on columns A AND B

    'Concatenate the 2 values as 1 - can be used to concatenate any number of values
    With Range("D2:D25001")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]&RC[-2]"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    'If formula sums the range-to-sum where the values are the same
    With Range("E2:E25001")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=R[-1]C[-1],RC[-2]+R[-1]C,RC[-2])"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    'Sort the range of returned values to place the largest values above the lower ones
    Range("A1:E25001").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Key2:=Range("E1"), Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Clear

    'If formula returns the maximum value for each concatenated value match &
    'is therefore the equivalent of using a Sumifs formula
    With Range("F2:F25001")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],R[-1]C,RC[-1])"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: I tested it on my own computer and got 2secs with 100'000 rows! Good stuff! Thanks for the effort.

Comment: You're welcome, and it goes without saying that the same principle can be applied to COUNTIFS.

Comment: This answer has an updated version here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939776/faster-way-of-using-sumifs-with-vba/64939999#64939999

Answer (score 3):

Give this a whirl

```
Sub test()
    StartTimer = Now()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D6285")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Tabelle1[KUNDENBESTELLNR],Test!RC[-3],Tabelle1[ANZAHL NACHFRAGE])"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    EndTimer = Now()
    MsgBox (DateDiff("s", StartTimer, EndTimer))
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok. Got it. Replace my tedious method of writing values in the same cells. TIL Way more efficient than what've been doing for a while now. Awesome! In total, it took the time to run through the code down to 50 seconds. 1 second better than my best so far.

Comment: :) glad it helped, I think you're now at the mercy of Excel and its function processing speed

Comment: I also tried adding application.screenupdating=false oddly that actually made it slower (52 seconds)

Comment: For this, it's unlikely that it would make any difference. Screen updating only stops excel re-drawing, since you aren't looping, it would only need to redraw twice anyway

Comment: Kyle, one question / idea. When I perform the same task in PivotTables, it is lightning fast (<1s). Any idea why?

Comment: Not specifically, but I'd guess it's to do with how excel processes data in pivot tables, they're optimizes for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

My version was inspired by kevin999's solution.

++ works with unsorted sumif criteria
++ will bring the rows back to the original order

-- doesn't support multiple criteria columns

Please note: The columns containing the criteria and the data to sum up must be one next to another.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Execute()
Call FasterThanSumifs(1)
End Sub

Private Sub FasterThanSumifs(Criteria As Long)
'Expects two coloumns next to each other:
'SumIf criteria (left side)
'SumIf data range (right side)

Dim SumRange, DataNumber, HelpColumn, SumifColumn, LastRow As Long
SumRange = Criteria + 1
DataNumber = Criteria + 2
HelpColumn = Criteria + 3
SumifColumn = Criteria + 4
LastRow = UF_LetzteZeile()

Columns(DataNumber).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns(HelpColumn).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns(SumifColumn).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

'Remember data order
Cells(2, DataNumber).Value = 1
Cells(2, DataNumber).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, DataNumber), Cells(LastRow, DataNumber)), Type:=xlFillSeries

'Sort the range of returned values to place the largest values above the lower ones
Range(Cells(1, Criteria), Cells(LastRow, SumifColumn)).Sort Key1:=Columns(Criteria), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear

'If formula sums the range-to-sum where the values are the same
With Range(Cells(2, HelpColumn), Cells(LastRow, HelpColumn))
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=R[-1]C[-3], RC[-2] + R[-1]C,RC[-2])"
    '.Value = .Value
End With

'If formula returns the maximum value for each concatenated value match &
'is therefore the equivalent of using a Sumifs formula
With Range(Cells(2, SumifColumn), Cells(LastRow, SumifColumn))
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]=R[+1]C[-4], R[+1]C, RC[-1])"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Columns(HelpColumn).Delete

'Sort the range in the original order
Range(Cells(1, Criteria), Cells(LastRow, SumifColumn)).Sort Key1:=Columns(DataNumber), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear

Columns(DataNumber).Delete

End Sub
```