# Need help optimizing SUMIFS within VBA

Tags: vba, optimization, excel, sumifs

I've been using this site for months now to help get me started in my early coding career and this is my first post here.  I apologize if I missed this question while searching the forums yesterday.  I had a spreadsheet with roughly 6,000 active Sumifs referencing a table of 500,000+ rows.  As you can imagine, this took a moment to calculate.  I've written them into VBA so they only calculate when the user chooses to do so.  However, with so many sumifs, the code takes about 3-5 minutes to run through.  I'm looking for ways to speed this up for a better end-user experience.  I'll post how I'm performing the sumifs below.  Just for some context, this is performing the sumifs on the same group of users twice, but with one different criteria.  Let me know if I left out any pertinent information.

```
For i = 1 To 12
    Range("Emp_Utility").Offset(1, i).Activate
    Do Until Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2) = ""
        ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Hrs, Emp, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2), Y, Cells(4, ActiveCell.Column), M, Cells(3, ActiveCell.Column))
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
Next i

For a = 1 To 12
    Range("Emp_Billable").Offset(1, a).Activate
    Do Until Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 30) = ""
        ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Hrs, Emp, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2), Y, Cells(4, ActiveCell.Column), M, Cells(3, ActiveCell.Column), Bill, "No")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
Next a
```

Comment: Sounds like you should look into pivot tables.

Comment: I wish I could.  Not Dynamic enough for what I need.  This is just one step of several in the process of exporting instantaneous reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the ranges into variant arrays and then write the SUMIFS in the code, not using formulas. If you need examples let me know and I'll guide you through it.

EDIT: No prob. Here's an example then.

```
Sub example()

    Dim EmpUtil, EmpBillable As Variant   ' Creates variant array

    EmpUtil = Range("Emp_Utility")        'Places Range into EmpUtil Array
    EmpBillable = Range("Emp_Billable")   'Places Range into EmpBillable Array

    For x = LBound(EmpUtil) To UBound(EmpUtil)   'Cycles through EmpUtil Rows
        'Do comparisons and additions here
        'References to arrays should be something like
        ' "EmpUtil(x,3) = example" - for the 3rd column

        'for calculations on each column you cycle through each column for that row
        For y = LBound(EmpUtil, 2) To UBound(EmpUtil, 2)
            EmpUtil(x, y) = Calculation

        Next y


    Next x

    For x = LBound(EmpBillable) To UBound(EmpBillable)   'Cycles through EmpBillable Rows
        'Do comparisons and additions here


    Next x

    Range("Emp_Utility") = EmpUtil         'Places EmpUtil Array back into Range
    Range("Emp_Billable") = EmpBillable    'Places EmpBillable Array back into Range


End Sub
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Hi jlaverde,  I could definitely use an example.  I'm pretty inexperienced with arrays within VBA.  Thanks!

Comment: There you go if you need any other help let me know. Also, remember to upvote if this is helpful or accept the answer if this is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks! this definitely looks more efficient.  A quick question on performing the calculations. I have 12 columns, would I have EmpUtil(x,1) = calculation
EmpUtil(x,2) = calculation
ETC....

Comment: You could do them separate for make another for loop. I'll edit as example

Comment: That makes sense.  And one last question, do I use the sumif syntax just like a worksheet.function?

Comment: I would use if then else statements because I would rather know exactly what my code is doing. You might be able to use the function though.

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch in this section

    If EmpUtil(x, 1) = Emp Then

Emp is a range within a table...

Comment: It should be Emp.value if it is a referencing one cell.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider an alternative to SUMIFS (which can take forever to calculate) such as a combination of SUM and SORT. Please see the answer to [How to perform SumIf using VBA on an array in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975530/how-to-perform-sumif-using-vba-on-an-array-in-excel) which looks at using a SUM and SORT combination resulting in very fast calculations whilst still returning the same values as if a SUMIFS method had been used.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest to use array match method to work with **big data** in excel (Customers information, loan cards). You better turn off autoupdates at the begining of your code with using that sumif and then turn them on. Follow these commands:
Hope that this will help!

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

<Your sumifs code>

ActiveSheet.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```