# Conditional Sum in Excel with Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My data looks like this, it has 3 columns: Town Code, Ward Code and the corresponding Population of that Ward :

```
| Town  |  Ward | Population |
|  1000 | 10001 |     20     |
|  1000 | 10002 |     30     |
|  1000 | 10003 |     40     |
|  1234 | 12341 |     50     |
|  1234 | 12342 |     35     |
```

I am not able to write a code in vba that will be give me the sum of population for all Wards under a Town (ie total Population of a Town).
 Considerations:-
 I have a huge dataset.
 I have multiple sheets over which I have the same kind of data, with different Town ID's (also different number of Wards per Town). Please kindly help if you can take out some time out of your busy schedule.

Comment: Why do you need it in VBA. Why not use a SUMIF Function in Excel.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe

Comment: As mentioned, my dataset is huge, so it is a bit tedious to check and assign the range whenever the Town Code changes, you have to do it really vigilantly and will take a lone time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your solution

[How to perform SumIf using VBA on an array in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975530/how-to-perform-sumif-using-vba-on-an-array-in-excel)

```
 Sub FasterThanSumifs()
    'FasterThanSumifs Concatenates the criteria values from columns A and B -
    'then uses simple IF formulas (plus 1 sort) to get the same result as a sumifs formula

    'Columns A & B contain the criteria ranges, column C is the range to sum
    'NOTE: The data is already sorted on columns A AND B

    'Concatenate the 2 values as 1 - can be used to concatenate any number of values
    With Range("D2:D25001")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]&RC[-2]"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    'If formula sums the range-to-sum where the values are the same
    With Range("E2:E25001")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=R[-1]C[-1],RC[-2]+R[-1]C,RC[-2])"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    'Sort the range of returned values to place the largest values above the lower ones
    Range("A1:E25001").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Key2:=Range("E1"), Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Clear

    'If formula returns the maximum value for each concatenated value match &
    'is therefore the equivalent of using a Sumifs formula
    With Range("F2:F25001")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],R[-1]C,RC[-1])"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; I could get what I needed from this, thanks once again.